# MVC3 breaks Linq2Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been converting a site from MVC2 to MVC3 and while I have managed to get it working I am plagued by the error message

"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider+SingleResult`1[NutritionLabel3.Models.sp_get_ingredientNutritionFoomasResult]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'NutritionLabel3.Models.sp_get_ingredientNutritionFoomasResult'. "

This error comes from the Model layer that implements a Linq2Sql data layer.  This code works fine in MVC2.  I have conducted a number of tests by building new MVC3 sites with a new Linq2Sql interface to verify that this is repeatable.  A typical implementation of a Linq2Sql call in the controller would look like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        NutritionLabel3.Models.testDataContext dbContext = new Models.testDataContext();

        var nutritionData = dbContext.sp_get_ingredientNutritionFoomas(2, 1, 2);

        return View(nutritionData);
    }
```

It seems that the implicit type conversion message is very arcane.  Has anyone fought this battle yet in MVC3?

Any help would be much appreciated!!

PatC

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var nutritionData = dbContext
    .sp_get_ingredientNutritionFoomas(2, 1, 2)
    .Single();
```